# SQLAlchemy Query with multiple filtered aggregates

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Say we have a mysql pivot query (taken from an answer to pivto table question 
 [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)) with inner join.

```sql
select projects.org,  SUM(ivt_incidents.severity = 'SEV3') as 
sev3_count, 
SUM(ivt_incidents.severity = 'SEV2') as sev2_count, 
SUM(ivt_incidents.severity = 'SEV1') as sev1_count, 
SUM(ivt_incidents.severity = 'SEV0') as sev0_count, 
SUM(ivt_incidents.severity like '%SEV%') as total_count  from 
ivt_incidents inner join projects on ivt_incidents.jira_key = 
projects.jira_key group by projects.org order by total_count;
```

Looking for help in building sqlalchemy query:

```
response = db.session.query(
        func.sum(Incidents.severity).filter(Incidents.severity == 'SEV3'),
        Projects.org).\
    join(Projects, Projects.jira_key == Incidents.jira_key).\
    group_by(Projects.org)
```

If I run it, it will accept the query, however if I call

```
response.all()
```

> ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(WHERE ivt_incidents.severity = 'SEV3') AS anon_1, projects.org AS projects_org ' at line 1 [SQL: u'SELECT sum(ivt_incidents.severity) FILTER (WHERE ivt_incidents.severity = %(severity_1)s) AS anon_1, projects.org AS projects_org \nFROM ivt_incidents INNER JOIN projects ON projects.jira_key = ivt_incidents.jira_key GROUP BY projects.org'] [parameters: {u'severity_1': 'SEV3'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: On `.filter` clause call `Incidents.severity`

Comment: doh! what a typo :) thanks for the reply!

Comment: db.session.query(func.count(Incidents.severity),Incidents.severity, Projects.org).filter(Incidents.severity.in_(['SEV2','SEV3','SEV1','SEV0',''])).join(Projects, Projects.jira_key == Incidents.jira_key).group_by(Projects.org, Incidents.severity)
Gives me the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support<sup>✝️</sup> the SQL standard [aggregate FILTER clause](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) you're trying to use in `func.sum(...).filter(...)`, which gets compiled to

```
SUM(...) FILTER (WHERE ...)
```

Looking at your original query, you should pass the predicate expression as the argument of SUM:

```
response = db.session.query(
        func.sum(Incidents.severity == 'SEV3'),
        Projects.org).\
    join(Projects, Projects.jira_key == Incidents.jira_key).\
    group_by(Projects.org)
```

The reason why you get the error only after calling `Query.all()` is that that's when the query is actually emitted to the database. Before that you've just built a `Query` object.

<sup>✝️</sup>: There's a [plugin](https://github.com/svetasmirnova/filter_plugin) that adds FILTER support to MySQL by rewriting queries.